# Registering on Git Bash

Tags: git-bash

I am trying to register my username and email id in git bash using the standard command as below"

Console command:

```
    git config -- global user.name "kishokumar"
```

and similary for registering my email id. However, I receive an error saying:

```
"Error: key doesnot contain a section: global".
```

Any clues on whats the problem here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that exactly how you entered it (including all spaces)?

Comment: git config --global user.name "kishokumar", no space between -- and global

Answer (score 0):

No need for space and quotes:

```
git config --global user.name kishokumar
```

See [`git config` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> options `--system`, `--global`, `--file <filename>` can be used to tell the command to write to that location (you can say `--local` but that is the default).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have been using "-- global" instead of "--global". It works now after removing the space. Thanks a lot for your  help guys.
Feeling  silly :) 
Cheers